# Finding records of emigration from UK to Argentina in 1935

Tags: england, 1930s, emigration, argentina

My relative George Owen emigrated on 19 Oct 1935 with his two children from Southampton, UK to Argentina via ship to Buenos Aires. He was an experienced railway engineer and family stories say helped build the Argentine rail network. The last known address was in Buenos Aires but I've had no reply.

Where would any immigration, census and employment records be found?
What I do have is a passenger list on which he appears.

I have had had no success with main Family History websites.

Comment: Welcome to G&FH SE!  Thank you for having taken the [Tour] to learn about our focussed Q&A format which is quite different from bulletin boards, discussion forums and other Q&A sites you may be used to.  Please try to ask a single focussed question rather than multiple questions in one.  In this question I think you should just ask about emigration records, and then use separate questions to ask about Argentina Census and Railway Employment questions.

Comment: Also, if you include the name of your relative it may help potential answerers in their efforts to help you.  However, please do not mention his children's names because they seem likely to have been born less than 100 years ago which comes up against our Privacy Policy which is described in our [help/on-topic].

Comment: If you are willing to get back in touch with the Owen family, you could try reaching British descendants organizations, like ABCC https://www.abcc.org.ar/ They probably have resources about immigration as well. Just a thought.